# IE11 textarea loses focus if another textarea is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, internet-explorer-11, onfocus

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wa869yot/2/), using ie11 with open Console, input something into any `textarea` and then click into any other `textarea`. In console, you will see that `change` event for the first `textarea` is triggered, then this `textarea` gets `disabled`, but `focus` event for the second `textarea` is not triggered. Why?

In my case, I was able to achieve what I needed by using `readonly` instead of `disabled`, but generally this looks quite odd. A bug?

For `input type=text` it works as expected, for now I was able to reproduce it for `textarea` only.

Answer (score -2):

you need to put `.focus()` after disable `textarea`.

Please Check this I have update your **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wa869yot/4/sdfsd/)**

Comment: It does not work, it always sets `focus` on the last `textarea`, while I need `focus` on the `textarea` which I clicked on. Moreover, I do not need `focus` on any `textarea` if I did not click any of them (clicked just blank field outside, for instance).

Comment: please also notice my question is 'Why?', it is not 'What to do?'

Comment: First of all, my question is 'Why?' - as I noted before. I resolved my specific case by replacing 'disabled' with 'readonly', which was enough - and it is also in my question. Secondly, your approach does not work still. I need change event (i.e., something really changed) + I need to be able to focus any `textarea` (the one I clicked), not `prev`, or `next`, or whatever fixed one. Additionally, as also noted before, I do not want to focus anything if user clicks any other control on the page / blank area.

Comment: after second look: `$(this).prev().find('textarea').focus()` does nothing at all!