# IE11 doesn't want to focus on `disabled` element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to force text to only be enter-able in one of two text fields.

When one field loses focus I check its value, and if it is not empty I disable the other text field.

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <label for="textOne">textOne</label>
  <input type="text" id="textOne"/>
</div>
<div class="conatiner">
  <label for="textTwo">textTwo</label>
  <input type="text" id="textTwo"/>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#textOne").on('focusout', function() {
  console.log("focusout::\t"+this.id);
  if( $("#textOne").val() == "") {
    $("#textTwo").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("#textTwo").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});

$("#textTwo").on('focusout', function() {
  console.log("focusout::\t"+this.id);
  if( $("#textTwo").val() == "") {
    $("#textOne").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("#textOne").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

This works just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but it appears that IE11 does not support `focus` on `disabled` elements.

The only solution I've found is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071404/ie11-textarea-loses-focus-if-another-textarea-is-disabled), which is to use the `readonly` attribute, instead of the `disabled` attribute. This isn't a desirable solution for my application.

Is there a way to achieve this in IE11, while still using the `disabled` attribute?

What is the reason IE11 does not support `focus` on `disabled` attributes?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and answers.

*EDIT:* here is an example on jsFiddle which, when ran on IE11 will reproduce the issue explained in the post https://jsfiddle.net/ftqbop7a/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as that, instead of `focusout` use the `input` event:

```
$("#textOne").on('input', function() {
    if( $.trim($("this").val()) == "") {
    $("#textTwo").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("#textTwo").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});

$("#textTwo").on('input', function() {
    if( $("#textTwo").val() == "") {
    $("#textOne").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("#textOne").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

***[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftqbop7a/5/)***

To explain: on focusout is too late for IE to get the reference of the last operated input element, while `(on)input` event will, since it occurs immediately.

---

Want to simplify your code an WOW your boss?
***[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftqbop7a/6/)***

```
var $inp = $("#textOne, #textTwo");
$inp.on("input", function() {
   $inp.not(this).prop("disabled", $.trim(this.value));
});
```

Comment: I like this answer. It solves the question I asked, so I'll mark it as the accepted answer.
I forgot to mention in original post that this should not trigger when the element's value changes, though. Otherwise I would have used `change` instead of `focusout`. Thanks!